# Make AIX load all shared symbols at run time?

Tags: c, reference, module, aix, dlopen

I'm on AIX 5.3, working with C.

I have an application (foo) that links in a shared library (lib1.so) at run time, then dynamically loads another library (lib2.so) via dlopen().  lib2.so uses some functions in lib1.so that foo does not use.  When I execute the application, I get an error similar to:

```
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol someLibFunc was referenced from module
/libdir/lib2.so(), but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found.
```

I don't believe that changing the dlopen() flags would have any effect, since my issue seems to have something to do with what symbols are imported when run-time linking occurs.  Is there some type of ld option I can use when building foo to force it to import all shared library symbols?  This same build works great in my Linux environment.

Comment: A wild guess: maybe the system has cached an old version of lib1.so that did not contain the function? (Run `slibclean`?)

Comment: I'm a developer for a large company, and slibclean is not made available in our AIX boxes, unfortunately (I don't know why).  However, I've developed shared libraries in the past without caching issues, so I don't think it's the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit.

I ran 'dump -Tv' on lib1.so and found that the function I expected to be exported was *not* there (although it *did* show up in nm, oddly enough).  The library was linked with -bexpall so all symbols should be there.  I dug deeper into the ld man page and saw that expall did *not* export symbols prefixed with an underscore (_).  The function I was trying to use began with an underscore.  I found the 'expfull' ld option, which exports symbols prefixed with an underscore, rebuilt lib1.so with that option, and everything is good now.

Comment: You can also make a list of export symbols in a file and use that with the -bexport option.  Its not that hard and you have more control.

Comment: Yeah, I've used that before. In this particular instance I want all available functions exported so expfull does the trick.